# Android emulator not opening in vs code

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

When I use `flutter in vs code I am able to start the android emulator easily but when I do it in vs code with react native I get this:

> Command 'React Native: Launch Android Emulator' resulted in an error (Error while executing command 'emulator -list-avds': Command failed: emulator -list-avds 'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. )

This error is killing me please help. I am using `expo CLI` with `react native`.

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **windows** you can go to **Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables** .
Then under **System Variables** find **Path** and double click on it and add this path `C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator`
or in windows 7 append the path with a `;` at the end of line.

Then click the OK buttons to get out.

If you already have a **Command Prompt** window open, close it then re-open and the `emulator -list-avds` command should then work.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you to solve your problem, mark it as the correct answer please. to help others know it  ;) @Dingus45191