# why can't the emulator not be detected?

Tags: flutter

[this is my vs code can't find my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9c4W.png)

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415],)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: First, you have to start the emulator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676121/android-emulator-not-opening-in-vs-code Check this